# shared pointer creation under a constructor

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2012, constructor, shared-ptr

Suppose I have a c++ class as

```
class xyz
 {
 ...
 };
class abc 
 {
  shared_ptr<xyz> ptr;
  ..
  abc():ptr( new xyz()) // line 1
   {
   }
 };
```

What is invoked on line 1 ?

```
make_shared<xyz>()
```

or

```
shared_ptr<xyz>(new xyz())
```

Does it depend on compiler?

Comment: You told it to call `new xyz()`, not to call `make_shared` - it would be pretty strange if your compiler calls something else than you stated, wouldn't it?

Answer (score 2):

The language has very little automatic use of library facilities.

There are some cases where the core language depends on the standard library, yes. E.g. you have to include the `<typeinfo>` header in order to use the `typeid` operator. And there's the call of `std::terminate` for an unhandled exception. But apart from such very special and fundamental cases, the core language and standard library are separate. With knowledge of necessary compiler and OS specific features you could implement the standard library yourself.

So, in short, there's no guaranteed magic replacement of your `new`-expression with a call to `make_shared`, but if the compiler can guarantee that the visible effect will be the same, then it *can* optimize that way under the *as-if* rule.

As far as I know there's no compiler yet that does that, as of Aug. 2016.

Comment: `make_shared` can hold bigger chunks of virtual memory than `shared_ptr(new)` if all that's left is a `unique_ptr`. Question is if that's an observable effect.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Yes, but I think on modern systems to get a state where that could be a possibility, the machine would slow down to snail's pace and beyond first, so one would have to wait years for it. Problems that could prevent the optimization include (1) custom allocator. Uhm, I can't think of more right now.

Comment: overloaded `operator new` would be another weird edge case.